# How can I cast a base smart pointer into the derived one in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Code :

```
class Base {
    ...
};

class Derived : public Base {
    void OnlyOwnedByDerived{
        ...
    }
};
```

The question is :
1. If I used a smart pointer of the Base class to reference the Derived one, the reason why I do so is that I want to get the benefit of dynamic binding which only fits virtual functions. But if I want to to use the function that is **only owned by the derived class**, what should I do ?
`static_cast` between the smart pointer of different class gives me an error...

2. The most direct way I can come up with is use raw pointer rather than smart one...

Comment: Close-voters should note that this question is not about `shared_ptr`. That word is not mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11, there is the [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Which you can use:

```
void func(std::shared_ptr<Base> b){
    b->VirtualBaseFunction();
    if(auto d = dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(b)){
         d->DerivedSpecificFunction():
         ....more code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`. This will return an empty `shared_ptr` if the cast is not successful.

You could potentially also use `dynamic_cast` directly on the pointer managed by the smart pointer, if you don't want the ownership to be shared between the returned derived pointer:

```
smart_ptr_type<Base> x = ...;
auto* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(x.get());
```

Comment: I don't see a constraint to `shared_ptr` only; I don't even see it mentioned. So as the question stands, this is at best a comment. In the case of `shared_ptr`...

Comment: Because there's not enough information, I have to make -some- assumption. Since all smart pointer types in the standard library can be converted to shared_ptr, it can be thought of as the "lowest common denominator". If they're using boost, then this should give them enough information to locate `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast`. You're welcome to ask for more specific information and answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For the smart pointer itself it depends on the smart pointer. A smart pointer to `Derived` is not a class derived from that kind of smart pointer to `Base`. 
But you can cast the raw pointer. For that  you have `static_cast` if you know the pointee is of derived type, and `dynamic_cast` for when  you don't know (or just desire the checking) and the base class is polymorphic.

Note: Ownership assumptions can be broken if the raw pointer is downcasted and then used to construct a new smart pointer. For this case the original smart pointer's ownership should be released first. Usually that's a member function called `release`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base
{
    int x;
};

struct Derived
    : Base
{
    void foo() const { std::cout << x << "\n"; }
    Derived( int const value ): Base{ value } {}
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using std::unique_ptr;
    unique_ptr<Base> p_base{ new Derived{ 42 } };

    #ifdef CHECK
        unique_ptr<Derived> p_directly_converted{ p_base };     // !Nyet
    #endif

    unique_ptr<Derived> p_derived{
        static_cast<Derived*>( p_base.release() )
        };
    p_derived->foo();
}
```

`std::unique_ptr` doesn't have an associated function that performs this downcast, so it must be done manually via either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` (for a polymorphic base), plus `release`.

However, `std::shared_ptr` has associated functions `static_pointer_cast`, `dynamic_pointer_cast` and `const_pointer_cast`, and other smart pointers may have ditto functions – but this depends very much on the smart pointer.